# Subir imagenes en springboot (Guardar imagenes en la base de datos)

Tags: java, spring-boot, imagen

### Estoy intentando guardar imagenes en la base de datos y no me estaria funcionando.Agradezco la ayuda.

*Estuve averiguando y probando.Busque videos en youtube pero no logro saber si esta bien, si alguien podria ayudarme si voy en buen camino para hacer esto se lo agradezco*

Mi clase Paciente extiende de Persona , donde tiene el atributo:

> private String img;

Aca les dejo el codigo que tiene que ver con el manejo de imagenes.

**Paciente Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/crearPaciente")
    public ResponseEntity<Paciente> crearPaciente(
            @RequestBody Paciente pacienteRequest,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {
            Paciente paciente = service.crearPacienteConHistorial(pacienteRequest, file);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(paciente, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

**Servicio para guardar el paciente :**

```
@Override
    public Paciente crearPacienteConHistorial(Paciente paciente, MultipartFile file) {
        User user = userService.findByEmail(paciente.getEmail()).orElse(null);

        if(user != null){
            paciente.setUser(user);
        }

        // Crear y guardar el historial médico
        HistorialMedico historialMedico = new HistorialMedico();
        // Configurar propiedades específicas del historial médico
        historialMedico.setPaciente(paciente); // Establecer la relación inversa al paciente

        // Guardar el historial médico en la base de datos
        historialMedicoService.saveHistorial(historialMedico);

        // Configurar otras propiedades del paciente según los datos en pacienteRequest
        paciente.setHistorialMedico(historialMedico);

        //Guardamos la imagen del paciente
        guardarImagen(paciente.getId(),file);

        // Guardar el paciente en la base de datos
        return repository.save(paciente);

    }
```

**Funcion de paciente para guardar la imagen:**

```
@Override
    public Paciente guardarImagen(Integer id, MultipartFile file) {

        Paciente paciente = repository.findById(id).orElse(null);

        if (paciente != null) {
            try {
                if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
                    String imageName = "imagen_paciente_" + paciente.getId() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
                    imagenService.guardarImagen(paciente.getId(), file,imageName);
                    paciente.setImgUrl(imageName); // Almacenar la ruta de la imagen en el campo imgUrl
                    return repository.save(paciente);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Manejar la excepción de manera adecuada (puedes lanzarla o loguearla según tus necesidades)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null; // Puedes manejar este caso de acuerdo a tus necesidades (puedes lanzar una excepción, loguear, etc.)
    }
```

**Imagen Service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ImagenServiceImpl implements ImagenService {

    @Value("${file.upload-dir}")
    private String uploadDir;

    @Override
    public void guardarImagen(Integer id, MultipartFile file, String imageName) throws IOException {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El archivo está vacío");
        }

        // Validar que el archivo sea una imagen (puedes utilizar librerías externas para esta validación)

        Path directorioImagen = Paths.get(uploadDir, id.toString(), imageName);
        Files.createDirectories(directorioImagen.getParent());
        Files.write(directorioImagen, file.getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] cargarImagen(Integer id, String imageName) throws IOException {
        Path imagePath = Paths.get(uploadDir, id.toString(), imageName);

        if (!Files.exists(imagePath)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("La imagen no existe");
        }

        return Files.readAllBytes(imagePath);
    }
}
```